# Do I need to wait for Xcode 10.3 to test on iOS 12.3?

Tags: ios, deployment, xcode10

Currently iOS 12.3 is released and latest version of Xcode is 10.2.1

I want to know to test my app on my physical device with iOS 12.3 I need to wait for Xcode 10.3 or is it possible to deploy apps using Xcode 10.2 on iOS 12.3?

I did not update my phone iOS and keep its version 12.2 since I don't know the answer to this question.

Comment: You can use Xcode 10.2

Comment: @RajeshKumarR Do you have any documented reference for this?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 10.2 with iOS 12.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**iOS 12.4 Beta 2 Release Notes**

> The iOS 12.2 SDK provides support for developing iOS apps for iPhone,
>   iPad, or iPod touch devices running iOS 12.4. The SDK comes bundled
>   with Xcode 10.2.1 available from the Mac App Store

**iOS 12.3 Release Notes**

> The iOS 12.2 SDK provides support for developing iOS apps for iPhone,
>   iPad, or iPod touch devices running iOS 12.3. The SDK comes bundled
>   with Xcode 10.2.1 available from the Mac App Store.

Reference:

1. [iOS 12.4 Beta 2 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_release_notes/ios_12_4_beta_2_release_notes)
2. [iOS 12.3 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_release_notes/ios_12_3_release_notes)